# PHP/HTML5: Assign Latitude Longitude to variables

Tags: php, html, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm new to PHP/HTML5. I found the following HTML5 example to get device latitude and longitude. But it's just an example by showing the lat/long upon a button click.

**Problem:**
What I need is, when user submit a form, I will INSERT the value into MySQL.
At this moment, I wanted to get the device lat/long and assign as variables so I can use the variables to INSERT into MySQL at the same time. I have ready table in my DB for both lat and long.

Please give me some hint, guide, tips to me to achieve what I need. Help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="';
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo '">
  <p>Please complete this form and I will contact you as soon as possible. Thank you.</p>
  <p>
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <label for="phone">Contact Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
    <label for="message">Message to Owner</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Info" />
  </p>
</form>
```

**New Simpler Form Example with suggested code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>FurkidTag.com</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<title>Sample Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
$(function() {

    $("input[name='latitude']").val(position.coords.latitude);
    $("input[name='longitude']").val(position.coords.longitude) 
});
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lat = $_POST['latitude'];
    $lon = $_POST['longitude'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>Latitude: $lat."; 
    echo "<br>Longitude: $lon."; 
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type='hidden' value='' name='latitude'/>
   <input type='hidden' value='' name='longitude'/>
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use AJAX to pass the values to PHP in another page, in this example I'm using [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to make the ajax request

```
$(function() {
   $.get('getPosition.php', {
    Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    Longitude: position.coords.longitude
    }
});
```

In your getPosition.php you have to get the values like:

```
$latitude = (isset($_GET['latitude']) && is_numeric($_GET['latitude']) ? $_GET['latitude'] : NULL;
$longitude = (isset($_GET['longitude']) && is_numeric($_GET['longitude']) ? $_GET['longitude'] : NULL;
```

And make your sql stuff

**UPDATE**
To bind the value to your input form

```
$(function() {

    $("input[name='latitude']").val(position.coords.latitude);
    $("input[name='longitude']").val(position.coords.longitude) 
});
```

In your form add two imput type hidden

```
 <input type='hidden' value='' name='latitude'/>
 <input type='hidden' value='' name='longitude'/>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lat = $_POST['latitude'];
  $lon = $_POST['longitude'];
  echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
  echo "<br>Latitude: $lat.";
  echo "<br>Longitude: $lon.";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");
      function getLocation()
      {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(bindPosition);
        }
        else {
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
      }
      function bindPosition(position) {
        $("input[name='latitude']").val(position.coords.latitude);
        $("input[name='longitude']").val(position.coords.longitude);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="getLocation()">


    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>Please complete this form and I will contact you as soon as possible. Thank you.</p>
      <p>
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <label for="phone">Contact Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
        <label for="message">Message to Owner</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' value='' name='latitude'/>
        <input type='hidden' value='' name='longitude'/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Info" />
      </p>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @EmilioGort, thank you so much for the example. But my form action is _SELF. So I assume I need to POST/GET the value at the same time when I submit the form.

Comment: Can you please provide some example to POST/GET the lat/long value upon submit the form?

Comment: Add the form to your original post, not to the answer, your edit has been rejected.

Comment: Very sorry, very messy, first time using StackOverflow. Apologize.

Comment: @EmilioGort is it correct I need to wrap the function with <script> tag above my form?

Comment: @EmilioGort, I have added new form code in my post with your suggested code. I have tried it but the lat/lon doesn't display anything. I have also tried to insert the function with script tag inside HEAD. Also not working. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: you have to add the php to processes your form

Comment: @EmilioGort I'm very very sorry. I don't understand what you mean. Can give the example code at your answer? Thanks a million... or better to copy my last example code and show the PHP code that you mean. Thanks again.

Comment: @EmilioGort, please help. I urgently need to solve this to complete my project. Need your guide to understand this better. thanks in advance...

Comment: @emiliogort, once again. Thank you very much. I will try the second update.

Comment: @EmilioGort, I have read the complete code and now I understand how it works and will modify the code to suite my form. Thanks so much.

Just one more question. What will happen if the browser doesn't support Geolocation? Will it print the error message and not loading the form? or the error message will not be shown?

Sorry my javascript knowledge almost zero cause I just started reading javascript book.